# Find type of array through Eclipse JDT API

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I want `IType` instance for `int[]`, how can I get it through:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.findType(String)
```

if I pass `int[]` or `[I` - this always gives me null.
It it possible to get `IType` for arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Quote: "it is not possible to obtain an IType for an array
as arrays are not represented in the Java model."

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/74495/